# How do you stop the www folder getting overwritten using phonegap in xcode 4

Tags: xcode4, cordova

I followed the instructions for using a phonegap template in xcode 4 and dragged and dropped the autogenerated www folder into the project.  The problem is that on each build it re-autogenerates the index.html which is overwriting my code.  How do I stop this happening each build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was a bug with the release. Try downloading 0.9.5.1 again and reinstalling the package. It should work now. You may need to set up your project again though.

Comment: Thanks Steve but the issue seems to be there in the 0.9.5.1 release - I will post on the phonegap forum

Comment: @petenelson it's been absolutely fixed and verified (lots of times). there's something wrong with your setup.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this issue see this link:
http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-iphone/issues/103

There will be a new installer soon apparently